# Can we use "Grease Pencil" to mask other objects?

Tags: compositing-nodes, grease-pencil, render-layers, masking, render-passes

I'm trying to use a "greasy pencil" to cut out other objects. Like this red cube in the example. The white cube and the pink circle are in a collection. I want to make an object go through the middle of the cubes in After Effects, but the Circle also needs to be on top.

[image]

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: If you need a mask, I suggest you use tools for making masks. [Cryptomatte](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/compositing/types/matte/cryptomatte.html) is a good tool for masking and separating stuff in your renders.

Comment: This is just a passing thought, but if I needed to apply a mask to a 3D scene in grease-pencil fashion, I would probably just render the mask objects to a different layer and mask it out in the compositor.